# How to test correlations between ordinal outcomes and various kinds of variables?

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data

Running some analysis for 65 patients who have gone through a medical treatment post-diving.
I have a dependent variable which is ordinal: 1-bad outcome, 2-okay outcome, 3-good outcome.

I want to test some correlations with different independent variables:

1. Sex - nominal obviously. Should I use the Kruskal-Wallis test?
2. Dive depth - which is numeric in meters. Can I use univariate analysis?
3. Pre-treatment severity - ordinal variable as 0-no symptoms, 1-mild, 2-moderate, 3-severe. Kruskal-Wallis as well?